# ADXL345 generating interrupts without MCU

Tags: accelerometer

I wonder if it's possible to drive an [ADXL345](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL345.pdf) without an MCU on the board. That is, to set the ADXL345 to generate an interrupt on activity without needed an MCU on board. Could the register values stay persistent? If so, it could generate an interrupt without an MCU.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use an MCU?

Comment: The whole concept of "generate an interrupt" has no meaning without an MCU. What else would you be interrupting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no mention of eeprom or flash memory in the datasheet, so the reasonable assumption is that all settings are volatile. Hence you can't use this chip in any reasonable way without a processor.

Answer (score 1):

The ADXL345 does not have persistent registers.

In theory, it would be possible to build a circuit that generates an SPI signal that writes fixed values to some fixed registers, but this would require a big pile of discrete/logic components, and essentially reimplements a partial MCU, and results in more cost and space usage than a real MCU.

Additionally, the interrupts need to be cleared by reading registers.